# Table of contingency tables

Tags: r, lapply, contingency

I have a table with the following data:

```
ex = structure(list(A = c(482, 208, 227, 239, 783, 141), B = c(155, 
69, 63, 65, 255, 25), C = c(64, 24, 28, 29, 134, 34), D = c(408, 
180, 196, 207, 638, 104)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))


>ex
    A   B   C   D
E 482 155  64 408
F 208  69  24 180
G 227  63  28 196
H 239  65  29 207
I 783 255 134 638
J 141  25  34 104
```

I want to comput the chisq.test() for all pairs of rows for A vs B and for C vs D. This sounds pretty ambiguous to me so here is a concrete example:

```
   A   B       C   D
E 482 155   E 64  408
F 208  69   F 24  180

   A   B       C   D
E 482 155   E 64  408
G 227  63   G 28  196
```

... repeat for all pairs of E, F, G, H, I, and J

compute P values using chisq.tests() for each of these tables.

I have already done this, but it's output is in an annoying format. Basically I used `combn(rownames(ex),2)` to get the pairs, then wrote an lapply that went through the result of combn, constructed the matrices from the table, then and gave me the chisq of the matrix.

```
tests = combn(rownames(ex), 2)
tests = apply(tests,2,list)

testResults = lapply(tests, function(cat){
  test = unlist(cat)
  AvsBm = matrix(c(ex[test[1],'A'],ex[test[2],'A'],ex[test[1],'B'],ex[test[2],'B']),nrow=2, ncol=2)
  AvsBp = chisq.test(AvsBm)$p.value
  CvsDm = matrix(c(ex[test[1],'C'],ex[test[2],'C'],ex[test[1],'D'],ex[test[2],'D']),nrow=2, ncol=2)
  CvsDp = chisq.test(CvsDm)$p.value
  a = c(test[1], test[2], AvsBp, CvsDp)
})

testResults = data.frame(do.call(rbind, testResults))
names(testResults) = c('Var1', 'Var2', 'AvsB', 'CvsD')
```

The results looked like this:

```
> testResults
   Var1 Var2                AvsB                CvsD
1     E    F   0.918199692198075   0.608649272659481
2     E    G   0.432572099792864   0.790459437339736
3     E    H   0.358651246275942   0.723319426118104
4     E    I   0.960564133271506  0.0896848347203047
5     E    J  0.0144029906033956  0.0028292317888333
6     F    G   0.424982446036333   0.932706790402674
7     F    H    0.36295549985099   0.982958067120215
8     F    I   0.968631154321032  0.0684734899837275
9     F    J  0.0195800439529193 0.00302299304015596
10    G    H   0.998659183486833   0.999999999999997
11    G    I   0.354996420259763   0.102779771508206
12    G    J   0.107030315095613 0.00460404677366423
13    H    I   0.284826573788384  0.0801050087692166
14    H    J   0.123057932646613 0.00332480813135708
15    I    J 0.00951511015485216  0.0559833381301495
```

This works ok, but it feels like it should be a lot easier. I have to do a lot of reformatting of the table afterwards to get it into a pretty looking table. 
The ideal format would be two triangular tables one for A-vs-B and the other for C-vs-D.

Are there any built in functions that do this kind of thing?

Hope my question isn't too vague, Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
within(as.data.frame(t(combn(rownames(ex), 2)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), {
    CvsDp <- mapply(function(i,j)chisq.test(ex[c(i,j),c("C","D")])$p.value,V1,V2)
    AvsBp <- mapply(function(i,j)chisq.test(ex[c(i,j),c("A","B")])$p.value,V1,V2)
})
```

Result

```
   V1 V2      AvsBp       CvsDp
1   E  F 0.91819969 0.608649273
2   E  G 0.43257210 0.790459437
3   E  H 0.35865125 0.723319426
4   E  I 0.96056413 0.089684835
5   E  J 0.01440299 0.002829232
6   F  G 0.42498245 0.932706790
7   F  H 0.36295550 0.982958067
8   F  I 0.96863115 0.068473490
9   F  J 0.01958004 0.003022993
10  G  H 0.99865918 1.000000000
11  G  I 0.35499642 0.102779772
12  G  J 0.10703032 0.004604047
13  H  I 0.28482657 0.080105009
14  H  J 0.12305793 0.003324808
15  I  J 0.00951511 0.055983338
```

EDIT: as a triangular table, given `x` = the result above:

```
m <- matrix(nrow=nrow(ex), ncol=nrow(ex))
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- rownames(ex)
m[cbind(x$V1,x$V2)] <- x$AvsBp
```

Result

```
   E         F         G         H         I          J
E NA 0.9181997 0.4325721 0.3586512 0.9605641 0.01440299
F NA        NA 0.4249824 0.3629555 0.9686312 0.01958004
G NA        NA        NA 0.9986592 0.3549964 0.10703032
H NA        NA        NA        NA 0.2848266 0.12305793
I NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.00951511
J NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
```

For `CvsDp` just replace it in the last line.

Comment: Cool. Very useful. Any idea how to turn it into a triangular table?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative:

Step 1: Create an empty matrix and a `list` of the column combinations you are looking at

```
A <- list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"))
A2 <- sapply(A, paste, collapse = "vs")
myMat <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(ex), ncol = nrow(ex),
                dimnames = list(rownames(ex), rownames(ex)))
```

Step 2: Use the `FUN` argument for `combn` to get a vector of "p.values" from `chisq.test`. This will result in a 2 row by 15 column matrix.

```
csTest <- combn(rownames(ex), 2, FUN=function(y) {
  sapply(A, function(z) {
    chisq.test(ex[y, z])$p.value
  })
})
```

Step 3: Use `lapply` to create a `list` of the two rows as a `matrix`. Make use of `lower.tri` to automatically fill in the matrix.

```
setNames(lapply(sequence(nrow(csTest)), function(y) {
  myMat[lower.tri(myMat)] <- csTest[y, ]
  myMat
}), A2)
# $AvsB
#            E          F         G         H          I  J
# E         NA         NA        NA        NA         NA NA
# F 0.91819969         NA        NA        NA         NA NA
# G 0.43257210 0.42498245        NA        NA         NA NA
# H 0.35865125 0.36295550 0.9986592        NA         NA NA
# I 0.96056413 0.96863115 0.3549964 0.2848266         NA NA
# J 0.01440299 0.01958004 0.1070303 0.1230579 0.00951511 NA
# 
# $CvsD
#             E           F           G           H          I  J
# E          NA          NA          NA          NA         NA NA
# F 0.608649273          NA          NA          NA         NA NA
# G 0.790459437 0.932706790          NA          NA         NA NA
# H 0.723319426 0.982958067 1.000000000          NA         NA NA
# I 0.089684835 0.068473490 0.102779772 0.080105009         NA NA
# J 0.002829232 0.003022993 0.004604047 0.003324808 0.05598334 NA
```